# NFT Not Showing Up

Tags: solidity, remix, nft, testnets, opensea

Hello I finished every step of the video tutorial titled "How to develop an NFT Smart Contract (ERC721) with Alchemy - Beginner | Road to Web3" until the part where we go to OpenSea testnet and wait for the NFT to show up. I've checked in Remix and it says I have one NFT, but it has not shown up in either my MetaMask Wallet, nor my OpenSea account.

How can we solve this mystery?

Answer (score 0):

It is a delay between OpenSea and NFTs